# How to efficiently search Info documentation?

Tags: emacs, info

I was looking for documentation on `tr` program. As you would imagine the combination of characters `t` and `r` happens fairly often in English language... Although I was sure about the name, I wasn't sure about the name of the section it belongs to, so I had to display all nodes and try searching for something like `tr` or `tr(` and so on.

Isn't there a better way to do it?

Comment: If regexps are allowed you could surround tr in word boundaries.  That might not take you straight to your target but it should speed the search.

Comment: @BruceConnor I was hoping for something more in terms of a search by node name only. I'm also almost certain there must be such thing, if only I knew what it's called...

Comment: Yeah, there must be a straightforward command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm... I can only guess that the following *isn't* happening for you; however nodes for individual programs really ought to be listed in the top-level directory, and hence show up when you type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `info` <kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, from where you can simply use <kbd>m</kbd> `tr` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

However if you're searching for something which isn't in any of the directory files, the only convenient thing I know of is <kbd>M-x</kbd> `info-apropos` (which searches all of the indexes rather than the node titles).

And of course within a given manual you can use <kbd>I</kbd> to search its index, which is much faster than searching all of them.

**Edit:** This is tangential, but an excellent improvement in the upcoming Emacs 24.4 (currently undocumented in the NEWS file) is completion for Info node names in non-current manuals.

e.g. <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)` <kbd>TAB</kbd> now provides completions for all the nodes in the elisp manual, even if you are not currently viewing that manual.

This is an *extremely* welcome change!

Comment: I've used emacs for 30 years and I never knew about info-apropos.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know about either thing I could do, so this is really useful! As was my case - I searched for the info page `tr invocation` because that was mentioned in the man page. I wasn't sure what was the actual page title.

Comment: I might as well point you at these answers as well, as they might also prove helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10332184/324105 http://stackoverflow.com/a/14916790/324105

Comment: Thanks, that's useful too!

Answer (score 1):

[***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) can help here.  All Info commands that use *completion* let you take advantage of **Icicles** completion features.  This includes [apropos completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions#apropos_completion) -- regexp matching, which means that you essentially get on-the-fly `info-apropos` behavior, among other things. And it includes [progressive completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion), which means you can add additional patterns to progressively narrow your search.
When completing you can sort the candidates in various ways, including sorting Info nodes in book order for `g`.

`g` (`icicle-Info-goto-node`) lets you search both *node* ***names*** and *node* ***contents*** at the same time: Your minibuffer input can contain a second search pattern that is matched against the node contents. The completion candidates are those whose names match the node-name pattern you type (if any) and the node-content pattern you type (if any). Each pattern is a regexp (which includes substring matching as a simple case).

See [Icicles Info Enhancements](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Info_Enhancements) for more information.