# Is there command documentation and searching built into emacs?

Tags: emacs

Suppose I want to install a new package. To do this I need to remember that M-x package-install RET package-name is the sequence of keystrokes to type into emacs to do this.

If I forget this keystroke, my go to solution is to google the action I want to complete and browse through the results until I find the right command.

I suspect there is a better way to look up emacs commands and what they do though. If so, can anybody point me to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number one goto command for this would be the apropos-command, which is invoked by using `C-h a` (or `M-x apropos-command`), and then typing a search query for the command.

If you know the name of a function, you can use `C-h f` which runs the describe-function command to get more details about the command.

Lastly, if you know the key sequence, and want more details regarding the command you run, you can use `C-h k` - describe-key to have emacs tell you what command and the documentation for that command when typing a sequence of keys.

You can get a more complete list of help commands by typing `C-h ?`.

Comment: `C-h k` is the more informative version of `C-h c` (showing you the same details as `C-h f`, if you had the function name rather than the key binding). Also note that you can use tab-completion when entering function names with `describe-function`, so you can use that mechanism to assist when you can't remember the entire name.

Comment: @phils: Nice, I've never used that one :-)

Answer (score 1):

The built-in manuals are the other obvious places to look, and you can search each one using its index, or isearch through the full-text of the manual.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22380057/324105

Answer (score 1):

If you use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) then the equivalent of `apropos-command` is built into every command that reads a command name, and you can change the pattern on the fly to tweak the set of matches. See [apropos completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions).

Whereas with `apropos-command` you need to provide at the outset the regexp or the complete list of keywords to match (and you need to get them right), with **Icicles** you can modify/correct them incrementally, and you can add more patterns progressively ([progressive completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion)).

And when you have a set of matches for your pattern(s), you can see the complete [doc for each on demand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d%27Apropos#toc1), as opposed to searching the output from `apropos-command` (which only shows partial doc anyway).

In addition, **Icicles** [extends the standard apropos](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d%27Apropos) commands in various ways.